# QODBC Assembly Inventory By Site

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qodbc

We are trying to get assembly inventory levels by site.

`ItemInventoryAssembly` has the total but not divided by site.

`ItemSites`, which offers inventory by site, does not include assembly items.

However, the following xml request (ItemSiteQueryRq) returns assembly items as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <ItemSitesQueryRq>
            <ItemSiteFilter>
                <ItemFilter>
                    <FullName >The item's full name </FullName>
                </ItemFilter>
            </ItemSiteFilter>
            <MaxReturned>25</MaxReturned>
            <ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus>
        </ItemSitesQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Is this just a setting in QODBC?

How can we get inventory by site for assembly items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the table `ItemSites` has assembly inventory levels as well. But the item numbers are listed in other columns.

So for regular inventory the columns are `ItemInventoryRefListID` and `ItemInventoryRefFullName`,

And for assembly inventory the columns are `ItemInventoryAssemblyRefListID` and `ItemInventoryAssemblyRefFullName`